# How to upload video with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, post

I'm trying to upload a video while using Laravel. Though uploading images work fine for me when I change my controller line

```
echo '$file' . $file->getClientOriginalName() . '"/>';
```

to:

```
echo '<file src="uploads/' . $file->getClientOriginalName() . '"/>';
```

I only see `uploaded` written on a new page, but no video.

Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;


class UploadController extends Controller
{

    public function upload(Request $request)
    {

        if(Request::hasFile('file')){

            echo 'Uploaded';
            $file = Request::file('file');
            $file->move('uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());
            echo '$file' . $file->getClientOriginalName() . '"/>';
        }

    }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('upload', 'UploadController@upload');
```

View:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel</title>

        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">

                <h1>File Upload</h1>
                <form action="{{ URL::to('upload') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <label>Select image to upload:</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token">
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors? What exactly do you mean when you say it isn't working?

Comment: No not any error . just can't view it after i upload it

Comment: i only see" uploaded "written on a new page no video

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try like this:

Controller :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;


class UploadController extends Controller
{

    public function upload(Request $request)
    {

        if(Request::hasFile('file')){

            $file = Request::file('file');
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = public_path().'/uploads/';
            return $file->move($path, $filename);
        }

    }
}
```

php.ini files contains some limits that might affect this. Try changing these to high enough values:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
memory_limit = 32M
```

Comment: hank you for your answer :). , but still i'm getting a blank white page after i click upload .

Comment: an when i upload an image by it it shows me just the path on blank screen 

C:\wamp64\www\video post\public/uploads\0.jpg


please help me with it .

Comment: you are seeing blank screen because nothing is printed or returned. Did you check the folder "uploads" on your root ?

Comment: i got the problem it was the size

Comment: How to save the url or file name to the database

Answer (score 1):

```
 public function upload_video(Request $request){ 
             $data=$request->all();
              $rules=[
                'video'          =>'mimes:mpeg,ogg,mp4,webm,3gp,mov,flv,avi,wmv,ts|max:100040|required'];
             $validator = Validator($data,$rules);

             if ($validator->fails()){
                 return redirect()
                             ->back()
                             ->withErrors($validator)
                             ->withInput();
             }else{
                        $video=$data['video'];
                        $input = time().$video->getClientOriginalExtension();
                        $destinationPath = 'uploads/videos';
                        $video->move($destinationPath, $input);

                            $user['video']       =$input;
                            $user['created_at']  =date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
                            $user['updated_at']  =date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
                            $user['user_id']     =session('user_id');
                            DB::table('user_videos')->insert($user);
                            return redirect()->back()->with('upload_success','upload_success');
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($image)) {
                                                        
if($image->getClientOriginalExtension()=='gif'||$image->getClientOriginalExtension()=='svg' ||$image->getClientOriginalExtension()=='mp4' || $image->getClientOriginalExtension()=='avi'){

        $image = $request->file('image');
        $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = 'exerciseimages'."-".$name;
        $image->move('storage/courseimages/',$fileName);
    }else{
         

        $fileName = 'exerciseimages'.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
        if(!Storage::disk('public')->exists('courseimages')){
            Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('courseimages');
        }
        $amenitiesimg = Image::make($image)->resize(250,250)->stream();
        Storage::disk('public')->put('courseimages/'.$fileName, $amenitiesimg);

       
    }
```

Comment: Your first line wasn't formatted correctly. Also, please do not post answers that are just code. Explain how the code you've provided solve the problem and any assumptions or limitations you know of.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are multiple ways to do it but I'm used too to uploading the video using the code which is given below. I hope it'll help.

```
       if ($request->has('video')) {
            $video = $request->file('video');
            $video_extenstion = strtolower($video->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $allow_extentions = array('mp4');
            if (!in_array($video_extenstion, $allow_extentions)) {
               return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg' => 'Video format is not allowed only MP4 is allowed format']);
            }
            $filename = $id.'_'.time().rand(11111,9999). '.';
            $video_path = $filename.$video_extenstion;
            $video_url = $video->move('uploads/video/', $video_path);
        }
```