# How to upload video using laravel throwing post too large exception

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

can anyone show me how to upload and store video using laravel ?
whenever i try to upload a video it gives me post too large exception. 
I also changed values in php.ini file like post_max_size etc but did not worked

Comment: Would you like to show your code?

Comment: Sharing your work will help others to provide the better solution.

Comment: upload_max_filesize, post_max_size both needs to be changed and keep post_max_size greater than the upload_max_filesize.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload video with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138976/how-to-upload-video-with-laravel)

Comment: Other than php.ini, there are options to set max size in your apache or nginx server configuration. You may need to work there. Also there is option to increase size in .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, you have to set "post_max_size" parameter on php.ini file. If you are using php under the ubuntu, you could find the php.ini file on the path like: "/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini". The path may differ according to your php version or installation method.

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
```

and also for Command-line version:

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

Now, search for "post_max_size" using CTRL+w functional keys. The default value is

```
post_max_size = 8M
```

I changed the value to

```
post_max_size = 500M
```

press CTRL+O and then enter the "y" to confirm changes. do this flow for "upload_max_filesize" parameter; we changed it from:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

to

```
upload_max_filesize = 500M
```

now confirm the changes with CTRL+O and then exit with CTRL+X .
It could be useful to change some other parameters like "memory_limit", so on (check this article from [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-change-your-php-settings-on-ubuntu-14-04)).

Don't forget to reload new configurations:

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the php.ini options are getting loaded correctly. There are a lot of ways to overwrite this configuration file.

A quick Google search gave me this page: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php